# C# How to extend a class used by another class?

Tags: c#

Please let me explain my question with this example:

If I extend DataTable and DataColumn:

```
class MyTable: DataTable
{
    // Columns in here.
}

class MyColumn: DataColumn
{
}
```

My question is, how can I let the Columns of the MyTable class use the extended MyColumn, rather than the original DataColumn?

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to look into using a DAL design pattern (optionally coupled with ORM), rather than directly binding to a specific data representation (e.g. DataTable).  If you abstract your persistence layer, and design so it is extensible (virtual methods, abstract methods, or simply interfaces), then problems like this become much simpler.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer

Comment: Wholeheartedly agree with @Merlyn Morgan-Graham. There are better ways to do this.

Comment: Do you mean the ADO.NET DataTable and DataColumn classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish, but deriving from the base objects is probably the best route. Give this one a spin...

```
    public class MyDataColumnCollection : InternalDataCollectionBase
    {
        private readonly ArrayList _list = new ArrayList();

        protected override ArrayList List
        {
            get
            {
                return this._list;
            }
        }
        public void Add(MyDataColumn c)
        {
            this.List.Add(c);
        }
    }

    public class MyDataTable : DataTable
    {
        private MyDataColumnCollection _columns = new MyDataColumnCollection();
        public new MyDataColumnCollection Columns
        {
            get { return this._columns; }
        }
    }

    public class MyDataColumn : DataColumn
    {
        public string MyCustomProperty { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {        
        MyDataTable t = new MyDataTable();
        MyDataColumn c = new MyDataColumn();

        c.ColumnName = "My Test Column";
        c.MyCustomProperty = "This is really cool!";
        t.Columns.Add(c);

        foreach (MyDataColumn mdc in t.Columns)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(mdc.MyCustomProperty);
        }        
    }
```

Source with custom KeyedCollection<>

```
public class MyDataColumnCollection : 
    KeyedCollection<string, MyDataColumn>
{
    protected override string GetKeyForItem(MyDataColumn item)
    {
        return item.ColumnName;
    }
}

public class MyDataTable : DataTable
{
    private MyDataColumnCollection _columns = new MyDataColumnCollection();
    public new MyDataColumnCollection Columns
    {
        get { return this._columns; }
    }
}

public class MyDataColumn : DataColumn
{
    public string MyCustomProperty { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    MyDataTable t = new MyDataTable();
    MyDataColumn c = new MyDataColumn();

    c.ColumnName = "My Test Column";
    c.MyCustomProperty = "This is really cool!";
    t.Columns.Add(c);

    foreach (MyDataColumn mdc in t.Columns)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(mdc.MyCustomProperty);
    }

    MyDataColumn testColumn = t.Columns["My Test Column"];
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(testColumn.MyCustomProperty);
}
```

Solution with C# Extensions:

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static void UpdateValue(this DataTable dt)
        {
            // add code to update data in the DataTable 
        }
    }   
}

// in another class...
DataTable myDataTable = (Get DataTable object);
myDataTable.UpdateValue();
```

Comment: This looks like what I want. I still have some confusions. According to "public new MyDataColumnCollection Columns", then the original "Columns" will be replaced by the new one, but it will still have the original functions of datacolumn, because the new one is extended from the original datacolumn. Am I right?

Comment: Moreover, the elements in the original Columns could be accessed with keys, How can I achieve this with an ArrayList?

Comment: Q1: True statement.  Q2: An ArrayList is simply what the original Columns collection uses internally.  You could always substitute this with your own collection.

Comment: Thanks. Q2 I figured out is achieved by the this[name] property.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Can you provide some details on the bigger picture?

Comment: I just want to add a few methods to the ADO objects, such as DataTable.UpdateSingleValue or DataTable.GetSingleValue. I am trying to do this with cast now. I don't know is this a right approach, extending ADO objects? I found the existing ORM frameworks are too complicate.

Comment: So why not simplify your solution and write a method like public static void UpdateSingleValue(DataTable dt)().  Have you looked into Extensions?  It's a way to "extend" an existing class.

Comment: Added an Extension example above.  That's probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If your MyColumns derive from DataColumn, you can put them in the DataTable cast as a DataColumn. Your MyTable could then extract the columns and up-cast them to MyColumn.

Please note that this isn't the best option; you might be better off using something *other* than ADO.NET 2. But if that's the route you have to go, that's an option for you.

Note: you should always test the type of the DataColumn objects before upcasting to a MyColumn, lest InvalidCastException become a problem for you.

Comment: After tried with @Chris Gessler's method. I got what I want, but things get too complicated after I added more stuff in. It looks like cast is a simpler way. You mentioned that there are other options. Do you mean the ORM or DAL frameworks? I tried a bit, but they seem to be too heavy for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use interfaces.

For example, define interfaces for IDataColumn and IDataTable.
Then each implementation of those would inherit from the interfaces.

Upon initializing a DataTable object, pass the the appropriate MyColoum1, MyColoum2, etc.
This is much like polymorphism, only the interfaces alows you to define an absolute contract, without any specific implementation.

Comment: This would be fine, except that DataTable and DataColumn are existing types that @Jfly is apparently attempting to leverage, and they don't use or define abstracts/contracts/interfaces.